# Minitest logger outputting more information than I want

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest

I'm using `Minitest` with my `Sinatra` application to do TDD. Every time I run my test I see the database transactions (below) plus the actual test result (not shown). How can I keep it from showing the database transactions.

```
 Started with run options --seed 1738

 D, [2014-11-24T15:28:45.228645 #46736] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  SELECT @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS0:00,  ETA: ??:??:??
 D, [2014-11-24T15:28:45.230452 #46736] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0
 D, [2014-11-24T15:28:45.231070 #46736] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  SELECT DATABASE() as db
 D, [2014-11-24T15:28:45.232766 #46736] DEBUG -- :    (1.6ms)  select table_name from information_schema.views where table_schema = 'pajama_test'
 D, [2014-11-24T15:28:45.233105 #46736] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `books` LIMIT 1)
 D, [2014-11-24T15:28:45.233334 #46736] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `colleges` LIMIT 1)
 D, [2014-11-24T15:28:45.233546 #46736] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `colleges_departments` LIMIT 1)
 ...
```

Comment: Set log mode to info for test environment.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `$DEBUG` global is set, and so you are getting the debug information.

You can correct this by setting your desired log level as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set the log level to `INFO`:

```
configure :test do
  set :logging, Logger::INFO
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe your tests are running in `:development` env? Try to `before do ; logger.level = Logger::INFO ; end` — this must help.

Comment: I checked tests, they are running in `test` env. I also tried to put the code in `before` block, tried disabling logging but still no luck.

Comment: I figured out it was ActiveRecord logging and not Sinatra one.